# how do I fix error dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-W36e5C/4-libp11-kit-gnome-k in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, wine, dpkg

```
(Reading database ... 602386 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-wine1.6-amd64_1%3a1.6.2-0ubuntu14_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking wine1.6-amd64 (1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-W36e5C/0-wine1.6-amd64_1%3a
1.6.2-0ubuntu14_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wine/olecli32.dll.so', which is 
also in package libwine:amd64 5.0-3ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../1-wine1.6-i386_1%3a1.6.2-0ubuntu14_i386.deb ...
Unpacking wine1.6-i386:i386 (1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-W36e5C/1-wine1.6-i386_1%3a1
.6.2-0ubuntu14_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/wine/jscript.dll.so', which is als
o in package libwine:i386 5.0-3ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../2-wine1.6_1%3a1.6.2-0ubuntu14_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking wine1.6 (1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-W36e5C/2-wine1.6_1%3a1.6.2-
0ubuntu14_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/wine/fonts/vgas1257.fon', which is also in pack
age fonts-wine 5.0-3ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../3-libp11-kit-gnome-keyring_3.18.3-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:amd64 (3.18.3-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-W36e5C/3-libp11-kit-gnome-k
eyring_3.18.3-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/p11-kit/modules/gnome-keyring.module', which is
 also in package gnome-keyring-pkcs11:amd64 3.36.0-1ubuntu1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Preparing to
 unpack .../4-libp11-kit-gnome-keyring_3.18.3-0ubuntu2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386 (3.18.3-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-W36e5C/4-libp11-kit-gnome-k
eyring_3.18.3-0ubuntu2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/p11-kit/modules/gnome-keyring.module', which is
 also in package gnome-keyring-pkcs11:amd64 3.36.0-1ubuntu1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Preparing to
 unpack .../5-libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpng12-0:amd64 (1.2.54-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-W36e5C/5-libpng12-0_1.2.54-
1ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to install new version of '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0': No such
 file or directory
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Preparing to
 unpack .../6-libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libpng12-0:i386 (1.2.54-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-W36e5C/6-libpng12-0_1.2.54-
1ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 unable to install new version of '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0': No su
ch file or directory
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Errors were 
encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-W36e5C/0-wine1.6-amd64_1%3a1.6.2-0ubuntu14_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-W36e5C/1-wine1.6-i386_1%3a1.6.2-0ubuntu14_i386.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-W36e5C/2-wine1.6_1%3a1.6.2-0ubuntu14_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-W36e5C/3-libp11-kit-gnome-keyring_3.18.3-0ubuntu2_amd64.d
eb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-W36e5C/4-libp11-kit-gnome-keyring_3.18.3-0ubuntu2_i386.de
b
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-W36e5C/5-libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-W36e5C/6-libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Can you add some more information about what you were doing?

Answer (score 0):

Try these two commands to re-install `winehq`:

```
sudo apt remove wine winehq-stable
```

and

```
sudo apt install wine winehq-stable
```

This can solve the problem.

Comment: The above answer is fixed, my the problem.